# Calling JavaScript function from Objective c

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application for iphone.I need to call a javascript function into my objective c class .Is that possible??

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
```

Comment: Wow, is there a `"(NSCoffee *)coffeeByMakingWaterBoilAndPassThroughCoffee"` in Objective C ? :D

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out a category I did arround NSString for getting JS and regular expressions:
[iPhone - evaluating JavaScript and Regular Expressions using UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890726/iphone-evaluating-javascript-and-regular-expressions-using-uiwebview/4890750#4890750)