# iPhone - evaluating JavaScript and Regular Expressions using UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, regex

In my iPhone project, I needed to be able to validate a string either by using a Javascript function or by using a regular expression.

This code was tested using the JavaScript and Regular Expressions from the jQuery code:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/dateISO
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/digits
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/creditcard

I searched for a complete solution and probably missed it, so I decided to pick the pieces up and implement NSString+JavaScript+RegEx...

I've posted it as an answer below, in case it's of value to anyone...

Reuven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the code listings, hope you find is useful:

**//
//  NSString+JavaScript+RegEx.h
//**

```
@interface NSString(JavaScript_RegEx)

// Built-in rules
+ (NSArray*) emailRule;
+ (NSArray*) urlRule;
+ (NSArray*) dateRule;
+ (NSArray*) dateISORule;
+ (NSArray*) numberRule;
+ (NSArray*) digitsRule;
+ (NSArray*) creditcardRule;

- (NSString*) javascriptValue;
- (NSString*) regexTestValue:(NSString*)value;

@end
```

**//
//  NSString+JavaScript+RegEx.m
//**

```
#import "NSString+JavaScript+RegEx.h"

@implementation NSString(JavaScript_RegEx)

static NSString* kUIWebViewWrapperForJS = @"(function () {\ntry {\n%@\n}\ncatch (err)\n{\nreturn err;\n}\n}) ();";
static NSString* kJSWrapperForRegEx = @"re = new RegExp(/%@/); return re.test('%@')";

+ (NSArray*) emailRule {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], // 0=RegEx
            @"^((([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+(\\.([a-z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])+)*)|((\\x22)((((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(([\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]|\\x21|[\\x23-\\x5b]|[\\x5d-\\x7e]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(\\\\([\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF]))))*(((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(\\x22)))@((([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.)+(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.?$",
            @"Please enter a valid email address.",
            nil];
}

+ (NSArray*) urlRule {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], // 0=RegEx
            @"^(https?|ftp):\\/\\/(((([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(%[\\da-f]{2})|[!\\$&'\\(\\)\\*\\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\\d|[1-9]\\d|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.(\\d|[1-9]\\d|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.(\\d|[1-9]\\d|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.(\\d|[1-9]\\d|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\\d|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.)+(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])))\\.?)(:\\d*)?)(\\/((([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(%[\\da-f]{2})|[!\\$&'\\(\\)\\*\\+,;=]|:|@)+(\\/(([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(%[\\da-f]{2})|[!\\$&'\\(\\)\\*\\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\\?((([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(%[\\da-f]{2})|[!\\$&'\\(\\)\\*\\+,;=]|:|@)|[\\uE000-\\uF8FF]|\\/|\\?)*)?(\\#((([a-z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\u00A0-\\uD7FF\\uF900-\\uFDCF\\uFDF0-\\uFFEF])|(%[\\da-f]{2})|[!\\$&'\\(\\)\\*\\+,;=]|:|@)|\\/|\\?)*)?$",
            @"Please enter a valid URL.",
            nil];
}

+ (NSArray*) dateRule {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], // 1=JS
            @"return !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(\"%@\"));", // expect a date
            @"Please enter a valid date.",
            nil];
}

+ (NSArray*) dateISORule {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], // 0=RegEx
            @"^\\d{4}[\\/-]\\d{1,2}[\\/-]\\d{1,2}$",
            @"Please enter a valid date.",
            nil];
}

+ (NSArray*) numberRule {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], // 0=RegEx
            @"^-?(?:\\d+|\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})+)(?:\\.\\d+)?$",
            @"Please enter a valid number.",
            nil];
}

+ (NSArray*) digitsRule {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], // 0=RegEx
            @"^\\d+$",
            @"Please enter only digits.",
            nil];
}

+ (NSArray*) creditcardRule {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], // 1=JS
            @"// accept only digits and dashes\n"
            "var value = \"%@\";\n"
            "if (/[^0-9-]+/.test(value))\n"
            "   return false;\n"
            "var nCheck = 0, nDigit = 0, bEven = false;\n"
            "value = value.replace(/\\D/g, \"\");\n"
            "for (var n = value.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {\n"
            "   var cDigit = value.charAt(n);\n"
            "   var nDigit = parseInt(cDigit, 10);\n"
            "   if (bEven) {\n"
            "   if ((nDigit *= 2) > 9)\n"
            "       nDigit -= 9;\n"
            "   }\n"
            "   nCheck += nDigit;\n"
            "   bEven = !bEven;\n"
            "}\n"
            "return (nCheck %% 10) == 0;",
            @"Please enter a valid credit card number.",
            nil];
}

- (NSString*) javascriptValue {
    NSString* jsForWebView = [NSString stringWithFormat:kUIWebViewWrapperForJS, self]; // convert to "JS-edible-by-UIWebView" 

    UIWebView *wb = [[[UIWebView alloc] init] autorelease];
    //NSLog(@"%s\n%@\n", __FUNCTION__, jsForWebView);
    NSString* result = [wb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsForWebView];
    return result;
}

- (NSString*) regexTestValue:(NSString*)value {
    NSString* javascriptWrappedRegEx = [NSString stringWithFormat:kJSWrapperForRegEx, self, value];
    NSString* result = [javascriptWrappedRegEx javascriptValue];
    return result;
}

@end
```

Enjoy, Reuven

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following `UIWebView` instance method?

```
- (NSString *) stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: (NSString *) script
```

Comment: Yes, I have. In my class below (that I posted as an answer to my own question, hoping it will be useful for others...) I'm using it.

Comment: Well then obviously this isn't a question and shouldn't be posted on this website!!

Comment: I'm sorry for possibly misusing/abusing the etiquette of the site. I was looking in this site for the answer, and couldn't find one, leading me to write one myself; And since I couldn't find the answer on the site, I assumed others may be looking for a complete answer, and hoping my answer will be of value...

Comment: I suggest deleting the question, seeing as it isn't a question.